# How can I create a belongsToMany relationship with Laravel JSON:API?

Tags: laravel, json-api, laravel-api

I am familiar with creating a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship using Laravel.

In my example, I have many `resources` that share many `activities`. I have been able to successfully create this relationship in their respective models:

```
// Activity.php

public function resources(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Resource::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

```
// Resource.php

public function activities(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Activity::class)->withTimestamps()
            ->using(new class extends Pivot {
                use HasUuids;
            });
}
```

I'll then use the `sync` method to create the relationship.

```
$Ids = ['9a4cf36f-7683-4656-9653-9a01e1edbca1', '9a5225f0-31f6-40be-8863-6e8de61ef29f'];
$resource->activities()->sync($activityIds);
```

I'm attempting to create this same relationship using the [Laravel JSON:API package.](https://laraveljsonapi.io/docs/3.0/schemas/relationships.html#belongs-to-many)

My `ActivitySchema` looks like this:

```
return [
    ...
    BelongsToMany::make('resources')->readOnly(),
    ...
```

My `ResourceSchema` looks like this:

```
return [
    ...
    ArrayList::make('activities'),
    
    ...

    BelongsToMany::make('activities')->readOnly(),
    ...
```

Using Postman, when creating or updating a resource, my request body looks like this:

```
"attributes": {
    "activities": ["9a4cf36f-7683-4656-9653-9a01e1edbca1", "9a5225f0-31f6-40be-8863-6e8de61ef29f"]
    ...
```

The error I'm currently getting when creating a new resource is:

> "detail": "The field activities is not a supported attribute.",

Usually that means I am missing the field on my Schema. I have verified that it's there, so I'm wondering if it's due to the relationship?

I have tried using a pivot model, but no success there either. Do I need to create a custom controller to handle this logic? I'm not having much luck finding any instructions on how to `sync` the models.

How can I create/sync the relationship using the JSON:API package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to check out [the tutorial](https://laraveljsonapi.io/docs/3.0/tutorial/06-modifying-resources.html) as it has an example of a many to many relationship; Posts -- Tags.

In addition to the "attributes" you want to update in your resource, you'll also need to include the relationships.

For example, your resource `PATCH` request body will look something like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "resources",
        "id": "676110ee-c302-4239-8eac-1f9e87ebaae8",
        "attributes": {
            "some_id": "01b77de1-d524-4794-af90-88f64dd68999",
            "name": "My Resource",
            "description": "This is some updated text!"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "activities": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "activities",
                        "id": "9a4cf36f-7683-4656-9653-9a01e1edbca1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "activities",
                        "id": "9a5225f0-31f6-40be-8863-6e8de61ef29f"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Now in the response that is sent back you'll see the relationship(s).

In addition to the above, you'll also need to update the resource request to allow for the `toMany` rule:

```
// ResourceRequest.php


public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        ...

        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'description' =>  'required',
        'activities' => JsonApiRule::toMany(),
    ];
}
```

If you follow the relationship, you should now see the data returned correctly.

```
"relationships": {
    "activities": {
        "links": {
            "related": "http://my.api.test/api/v1/resources/9a528648-37e9-4f58-b37c-f4e3a6cb478d/activities",
            "self": "http://my.api.test/api/v1/resources/9a528648-37e9-4f58-b37c-f4e3a6cb478d/relationships/activities"
        }
    }
}
```

If you pass in the `included` query, the api will send back the requested relationship in the response.

```
/api/v1/resources/:resource_id?include=activities

...

"included": [
    {
        "type": "activities",
        "id": "9a4cf36f-7683-4656-9653-9a01e1edbca1",
        "attributes": {...}
```